# How to 'remember' a user when he logged in -passport.js-phonegap

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, sails.js, passport.js

So I have a Node.js server based on the Sails.js framework and I have successfuly implemented passport.js in a way that:

**(login)POST /auth/local**: if validated returns ID,Username and Email address.

**(register)POST /auth/local/register**: when registered returns ID,Protocol,Hashed password, UserID and an accessToken.

Now in my phonegap(ionic framework) I need to keep some data to make a login request automaticly everytime the user opens the app. I used to save the passport and the username localy but I understood that its a very series security hole.

Should I use a more secure localStorage? Should I use at all? Should I just save the userID? please clear this issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you're not aware you should read [oatuh 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) protocol documentation. But I'm warning you that it can be quite complex and how you implement it, it's up to you.

This is package for **PHP** but in it's [wiki](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Choosing-a-Grant) it sums pretty well the four types of grant that you can achieve with oauth:

- Authorisation code grant
- Implicit grant
- Resource owner credentials grant
- Client credentials grant

In your case I think that [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) is enough, but then again that it's up to you.

I have found this two npm packages, that maybe can help you out [node-oauth20-provider](https://github.com/t1msh/node-oauth20-provider) and [Sails-OAuth2-API](https://github.com/lucj/sails-oauth2-api)

Comment: I'm using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-auth and im pretty Satisfied from it. It's seems to do the job and I dont want to get another 2 days of Headaches implementing another library  unless its necessary. But I didn't got the answer of how should I save the localStorage data on my phonegap app. Is it safe to save the user id(UUID) or do I have to somewhat get the token and save him.

Comment: Save the token, the token is something that you pass on every request, you can send it on the header. Now on your server side you can manage that token, by managing I'm saying that you can block it whenever you want, set permissions, etc. Even if you don't want to spend time implementing a new library,take a look at the oauth flow I think that might help you creating your login flow. Whenever your user sends his credentials he gets a token. That's what you store in your app.

Comment: I have two problems with this approach: the library I use is saving the username and email in the 'user' collection and the hashed password,protocol, userID, accessToken in the 'passport' collection.when I login, I only get the user data not the token... I could do another request with the ID to get the token but is that how I should do it? If I'm going with the token approach I also gonna have to build an action that search the token's user data. Does saving the userID is not a safe way? It will much simpler

Comment: Why would I implement another oauth library? the one that im using works just fine.... I just need to know what data to save in the phonegap client in order to 'remember' a user when he launches the application.

Comment: @MatanGubkin saving the userID it's not safe at all, that way I could generate random numbers and try to do requests to your API until I find a valid one. Sometimes we have to take one step back to take two steps forward. You can implement what you want in a cleaner and reusable way using oAuth 2.0, it's the most popular protocol used by google, facebook, twitter and many many more. Sooner or later you will have to use it so at least give it a try.

Comment: this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-auth is not oauth2.0? should I use some other library?

Comment: Reading the docs, sails-generate-auth is a wrapper around **Passport.js**  and if you look at the [documentation of Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/guide/) you have a section about [ouath 2.0](http://passportjs.org/guide/oauth2-api/) So probably you can accomplish what you want with that package.

Comment: Ok so I successfuly stored my accessToken that is created when a user signs up in the localStorage when a user logins. That means that on every request from now on I pass the token as a parameter and compare it with the user token on the backend am I right?. Although I'm using tokens now they are only access Tokens. I dont use refresh tokens at all. Are they are truely necessary? I could just build a page that creates a new token if it somehow get stolen.

Comment: That's up to you and how secure you want your application. Will your application be big enough with a lot of users and sensible data, that you really need to concern with expiring and refreshing API keys? Although you probably don't need that I advise you to leave your Cordova application ready for that. What I'm saying is on your cordova application whenever you make an API request and receive a 403 response, it means that your user should login again.